# Why does the IRS allow tax-deferred growth in a VUL?

Tags: united-states, irs, life-insurance

Why would the IRS allow your premium "over-pays" to be invested tax-deferred?  What's their motivation?  They already allow 401(k) so why this too?

Note: VUL = Variable Universal Life

Answer (score 4):

The IRS doesn't 'allow' anything. They enforce the tax code. This may seem a pedantic distinction, but it's actually pretty important.

The tax code is written by congress, and over the years, it's become a convoluted hodgepodge of code catering to special interests. The insurance companies are in competition with Wall St, and, in order to expand their business, started using the wrapper of an insurance product to enhance the features of their investment offering. i.e. They attracted more money with this tax perk. They did this via lobbyists and donation to congressional campaigns.